# How to improve z3 linear programming performance

Tags: c++, optimization, z3, linear-programming

I am trying to use z3 to solve an linear programming problem and observing very poor performance relative to GLPK. There are reasons why I would prefer to use z3 so I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing.

The problem is essentially bin packing. I have on the order of 500 weighted items, and 5 bins. Every item must be placed in a bin. Objective is to minimize the total weight in the largest bin.

The problem was solved within 1-2 minutes by GLPK. I have yet to see z3 terminate.

1. The [z3 optimization tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/optimization) suggests both a boolean encoding and an integer encoding for a similar type of problem. Is one of these preferred for performance reasons? Basically I'm wondering if you need to follow a certain pattern for z3 to recognize it as linear programming.
2. How do I know what method it's applying to solve the problem?
3. Is there a way to configure logging on z3 so you can see what it's doing.

By the way, I'm using the C++ API.

Comment: What's wrong with pure ILP solvers? Technically, this is not Linear-programming, but (Mixed-)integer-programming (which needs a lot of additional code on top of an LP-solver). Without ever having used z3 seriously, a quick code-search for the usual keywords in ILP makes me think there is no dedicated ILP-solver (not the typical cutting-planes you would expect) and you will always pay for the much more general theory applied (again: it looks like that to me). (GLPK is okay; but it's usually worse than Coin-OR Cbc)

Comment: @sascha There were a few reasons why I was interested in using z3. One is support for multi-objective optimization (computing pareto optimal points). Second was that documentation I could find suggested it could do MIP problems. Third was the MIT license to most easily comply with my company's license policy. But yes I can certainly look at pure ILP solvers.

Comment: The license-stuff is a good point (pareto-opt is probably more a modelling-task). Most/All good LP/MIP solvers are (sadly) (L)GPL. The only high-quality LP-solver with a more permissive license i know of is developed within googles ortools (glop) which is Apache 2.0. ortools should support MIPs too, but again i'm not sure how much of a classic branch-and-cut approach is taken (ortools has more of a constraint-programming origin).

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. I had seen COIN-OR CBC and Google OR tools. I'll take another look. I think CBC is Eclipse license which should be OK. Do you have any recommendations on the multi objective piece? Pagmo looks interesting https://esa.github.io/pagmo2/

Comment: Often performance is sensitive to the way things are modeled. You may want to try a few different formulations. Having said that, it is not unusual that CP and SMT solvers do badly on models where MIP solvers do very good. (The other way around is also possible).

Comment: Thanks both. I experimented with CBC (via Google OR tools abstraction layer) and it works like charm. Solves the same problem in a few seconds.